# internal calculator in xcode/iphone not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app that performs calculations and solves chemistry equations. 
for example, the equation pv = nRT

R = 0.0821. the rest are variables. In Xcode, on the iOS simulator, everything works just fine. for example, if in the iOS simulator, I enter:

p = 1, v = 2, R = 0.0821, T = 50

then I will get n = 0.4872. this is the same case if i put those numbers in the app on my actual device.

but if i change the numbers to:

p = .99, v = 2, R = 0.0821, T = 50

on the iOS simulator, then the answer changes to 0.4823. However, on my iOS device, the answer just displays n = 0.0.

Likewise, if I'm solving for T, and I set p = 2, v = 2, n = 1, and R = 0.0821, on the simulator it shows T = 48.72. It says the same thing on my own device. But when I change n = .99 instead of 1, it reads "t = inf" on my device, but T = 49.21 on the iOS simulator (as it should).

essentially, the problem is: if there is a number smaller than 1 in the numerator, it reads 0. if there is a number smaller than 1 in the denominator, it reads infinity. except for the R value, which I have preset in the inspector panel to R = 0.0821. it always works righting the simulator, but not on my actual phone. what could be happening?

My code:

note: p, v, n, R, and T are the names of the text fields as IB outlets. the value that the user is solving for is left empty. so if p.text.isEmpty means the user us solving the equation for p.

```
@IBAction func calculatebutton2(sender: AnyObject) {

        var pnumber: Double = (p.text as NSString).doubleValue
        var vnumber: Double = (v.text as NSString).doubleValue
        var nnumber: Double = (n.text as NSString).doubleValue
        var Rnumber: Double = (R.text as NSString).doubleValue
        var Tnumber: Double = (T.text as NSString).doubleValue



        if p.text.isEmpty {
            let product1: Double = (nnumber * Rnumber * Tnumber) / vnumber
            let productasstring = product1.description
            self.answerplace.text = productasstring
            self.answerequalslabel.text = "p = "
        }


        if v.text.isEmpty {
            let product1: Double = (nnumber * Rnumber * Tnumber) / pnumber
            let productasstring = product1.description
            self.answerplace.text = productasstring
            self.answerequalslabel.text = "v = "
        }

        if n.text.isEmpty {
            let product1: Double = (pnumber * vnumber) / (Rnumber * Tnumber)
            let productasstring = product1.description
            self.answerplace.text = productasstring
            self.answerequalslabel.text = "n = "
        }


        if T.text.isEmpty {
            let product1: Double = (pnumber * vnumber) / (nnumber * Rnumber)
            let productasstring = product1.description
            self.answerplace.text = productasstring
            self.answerequalslabel.text = "T = "
        }


    } // end calculate function
```

Comment: It could be number of issues - impossible to answer this without actual code. Do some debugging to locate possible source of the issue, then post the code that works unexpectedly.

Comment: The usual: Turn on all warnings and fix all warning problems, that gives the computer a chance to find your bugs for you.

Comment: the warnings are all turned on, and none are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast your n value as a Double value

```
n = Double(result)
```

Comment: i have done that (at least I think). I edited my post with my code above.